# Past participle and changing endings with auxiliary verb "avere"

Tags: verbs, pronouns, auxiliary-verb, agreement, past-participle

I have read many times that the endings of the past participle doesn't change when used in conjunction with the auxiliary verb "avere". However I am increasingly noticing that is is not the case. For example I recently came across:

> Li ho messi in tasca

Maybe this *particular* example is wrong or colloquial, I don't know, but I've seen it enough times to make me think this is acceptable. However, I can't find any reference to this in any of my textbooks, nor online. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a pronoun as object, the only allowed form is the one you used: nobody would say "*Li ho messo in tasca". With an explicit object, the participle is invariable: "Ho messo i libri in tasca".
When the pronoun is a direct object and precedes the verb, as in the example given, then the past participle agrees with the direct object.

Comment: Thanks. Simple. I don't know how I've overlooked this for so long.

Comment: ‘Ho messi i libri in tasca’ is allowed, but not much used nowadays.

Comment: @egreg can you please point out to a reference where I can find this use.

Comment: @user11731289 This is Pietro Verri: https://books.google.it/books?id=mQNQzMNHu_MC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=%22ho+messi+i%22&source=bl&ots=iPVGpB3bO6&sig=ACfU3U1fZxqYJ_3h0Zdi_sbMR3kZgjF8Ww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu79rihKnpAhXpwMQBHQ5tCugQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ho%20messi%20i%22&f=false

Answer (score 21):

Past participles definitely do change according to the object gender and number for transitive verbs when the object is a pronoun, like in your example. They do not, however, change if the verb is intransitive, even if its *passato prossimo* uses “avere”, like “ho pranzato”.

*(some examples, as requested in comments)*

**Transitive verbs - singular subject**

- *Ho visto una casa* — singular explicit object (*una casa*). Base participle form.
- *Ho visto due case* — plural explicit object (*due case*). Base participle form.
- *L'ho vista* — singular pronoun as object (*la*). Participle gains the pronoun gender.
- *Le ho viste* — plural pronoun as object (*le*). Participle gains the pronoun gender & number.

**Transitive verbs - plural subject**

- *Abbiamo visto una casa*
- *Abbiamo visto due case*
- *L'abbiamo vista*
- *Le abbiamo viste*

No effect on participle.

**Intransitive verbs**

- *Ho pranzato*
- *Abbiamo pranzato*
- *Claudia ha pranzato*

Again, no effect on participle.

**Tricky cases**

- *Le ho detto* — *Le* is not the object, but *complemento di termine*.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'd love to see it improved. In particular, you could provide examples of the different categories. I'd be particularly interested in "Ho visto Claudia"/"L'ho vistA", for instance.

Comment: @martina good call. I added some examples.

Comment: Complemento di termine = indirect object? If so, I guess that the initial sentence of your answer would be more accurate if rephrased to: "Past participles definitely do change according to the object gender and number for transitive verbs when the *direct* object is a pronoun"

Answer (score 6):

The past participle used with *avere* and the *passato prossimo* as tense doesn't change basing on the grammar gender and the plurality of the direct  object. You say *ho messo a posto il frullatore* and *ho messo a posto i temperini nel cassetto*.

Since there is *li*, the past participle is declined basing on the plurality of the direct object. For example, it's *Li ho messi in tasca.* In the case the sentence is referring to *cartoline*, for example, the sentence becomes *Le ho messe a posto.*

Answer (score 3):

The question of past participle agreement with auxiliary verb "avere" when direct object is present in the sentence is covered in sections 365 to 369 of the book *Italiano* by Luca Serianni. In section 365 this author explains:

> Si ha [...] obbligo di accordo quando il participio si riferisca a uno dei seguenti pronomi atoni precedenti: *lo, la, li, le*.

That is, agreement is compulsory when participle refers to one of these pronouns preceding it: *"lo", "la", "li", "le"*.

This book gives these examples:

> - "io vedo sempre lui che me *l'ha data*, questa libertà" (Pirandello, *Il giuco delle parti*, III 33).
> - "Di quei funghi si fece, in famiglia, un gran parlare: e i miei fratelli dissero alla mia nonna paterna [...] che *li avremmo cucinati e mangiati*" (Ginzburg, *Lessico famigliare*, 31).

As explained by [Treccani Encyclopedia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/), another case in which agreement of participle with direct object is compulsory is when the pronominal particle *"ne"* is used as a partitive with the function of direct object, as in these examples:

> - di film, *ne ho visti* parecchi
> - ho comprato delle mele e *ne ho mangiate* tre (Cordin 2001: 650).

There are other instances with auxiliary verb "avere" in which agreement of past participle with direct object is optional, with a tendency in modern Italian to not do such agreement. They are covered in detail in Serianni's book. Some of them are explained in [this article by Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/accordo-participio-passato).