# A question about using Ne with passato prossimo

Tags: pronouns, agreement, past-participle, past-tense, particles

In the sentence 
"Quanta cioccolata avete mangiato?"
The answer will be
"Ne abbiamo mangiate poca" or "Ne abbiamo mangiata poca"?
Does mangiare get an E because of Ne or does it get an A because cioccolata is a singular feminine noun?

Thanks!

Comment: The correct answer is the second one. Cioccolata is a singular noun. In this case “ne” works as a “pronome partitivo” and is used to refer to a quantity or part of it both in the singular and in  the plural. http://www.oneworlditaliano.com/grammatica-italiana/particella_pronominale_ne.htm

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! This is a related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/54/past-participle-and-changing-endings-with-auxiliary-verb-avere (maybe it's a duplicate, at least one of the answers address "ne" particle).

Comment: It is either “ne abbiamo mangiata poca” or “ne abbiamo mangiato poca”. If you found “mangiate”, then it's a misprint.

Comment: @egreg: But, it would be "ne abbiamo mangiato" referring to "cioccolata"?

Comment: @Charo A common trend is not to do “concordanza” when the pronoun is not marked for gender.

Comment: Being the subject clearly “cioccolata” I’d recommend the use of the feminine desinence despite recent trends.

Comment: @egreg: But this [article of Treccani Encyclopedia (2011)](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) says: "L’accordo del participio con l’oggetto è invece obbligatorio con *ne* usato come partitivo in funzione di oggetto".

Comment: Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: @Charo Grammars always lag behind usage. ;-) I'm not saying it's “correct”, just that it can be heard.

Comment: Can someone write an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Treccani Encyclopedia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/), agreement in gender and number of past participle with direct object is compulsory when the pronominal particle "ne" is used as a partitive with the function of direct object

> L’accordo del participio con l’oggetto è invece obbligatorio con ne usato come partitivo in funzione di oggetto

and gives these examples:

> - di film, *ne ho visti* parecchi
> - ho comprato delle mele e *ne ho mangiate* tre (Cordin 2001: 650).

So, according to this rule, you should say

> Ne abbiamo mangiata poca

because past participle "mangiata" must agree in gender and number with the direct object (which has been substituted by "ne") "cioccolata".

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is definitely "ne abbiamo mangiata poca" as already said in comments. Here "mangiata" gets a final A because it refers to "cioccolata".